# Cauchy integral formula for not necessarily star-shaped regions

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f(z)$ be analytic on a region $R$. Let $u, w\in R$. Suppose $C$ is a simple closed curve containing $u, w$. Is it true that $$f(u)-f(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(z)}{z-u}-\frac{f(z)}{z-w}\,dz\,?$$

If $R$ is star-shaped, then the result follows directly from the Cauchy integral formula. But I only learned the Cauchy integral formula for star-shaped regions. Are there other subtleties to be dealt with? What if $R$ is not star-shaped?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: According to Gamelin, p. 113, the CIF extends to bounded domains $D$ with piecewise smooth boundary such that $f(z)$ is analytic on $D$ and $f(z)$ extends smoothly to the boundary of $D$. Gamelin defines a domain as an open set such that any two points in the set can be connected by a broken line segment wholly in the set.

Comment: @AdrianKeister that doesn't seem right if the curve is not homotopic to a point in $D$

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki: Wouldn't a simply-connected open set be homotopic to a point inside it?

Comment: @AdrianKeister yes, but you didn't require that $D$ is simply connected?

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki: That's what the whole business of broken line segments was all about. He doesn't mean broken as in disconnected, he just means that the slope can change instantaneously. That is, two points in the set are always connected by piecewise-linear curves.

Comment: @AdrianKeister but doesn't this just mean that $D$ is path connected? that is not the same thing as simply connected

Comment: Ah, I see what you're after. Yeah, that could be a problem. Emailing Dr. Gamelin... I'll post back here afterwards. Incidentally, I think it does work for simply connected domains - you don't have to have star-shaped sets.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy's Theorem: Suppose that $R$ is an open set in $ \mathbb C$ and that $f:R \to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic. Furthermore let $c:[a,b] \to R$ a closed and piece-wise $C^1$ curve with $ ind_c(v)=0$ for all $v$ not in $R$, then

$$f(z) \cdot  ind_c(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw$$

for all $z \in R \setminus c[a,b]$.

$ind_c( \cdot)$ denotes the winding number.

Comment: do you have a definition of the index that doesn't make this more or less trivial?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number